# Warm start of simplex algorithm after update of constraint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Assume we found an optimal solution $\mathbf{x}_1$ of the linear program 
\begin{gather}
\max \mathbf{n}^T\mathbf{x}\mbox{ s.t. }A\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}\tag{1}
\end{gather} using the simplex algorithm. Now we update the matrix $A$ by a bijective mapping represented by the matrix $M$. Then clearly $\mathbf{y} = M\mathbf{x}_1$ is a (primal) feasible solution of the linear program 
\begin{gather}
\max \mathbf{n}^T\mathbf{x}\mbox{ s.t. }AM^{-1}\mathbf{x}\leq \mathbf{b},\tag{2}
\end{gather}
but $\mathbf{y}$ is not necessarily optimal. My question is whether the basis factorization obtained by the prior simplex algorithm is still valid for $(2)$ (which would allow a warm start) or not. (In the later case I had to compute a basis factorization form the given feasible solution $\mathbf{y}$.)

Obviously, I could do the following: Instead of solving $(2)$, I could solve the linear program
\begin{gather}
\max \mathbf{m}^T\mathbf{x}\mbox{ s.t. }A\mathbf{x}\leq\mathbf{b},\tag{3}
\end{gather}
where $\mathbf{m}=M^T\mathbf{n}$. Since the constraint system of $(3)$ is the same as in $(1)$, the basis factorization is still valid and could be used for a warm start. Furthermore, for any optimal solution $\mathbf{x}_3$ of $(3)$ we have that $\mathbf{x}_2=M\mathbf{x}_3$ is an optimal solution of $(2)$. However, I dont't want to use this approach since after the update of $A$ by $M^{-1}$ some additional modifications (adding columns) will follow.