# Nonsingularity of submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'm still working on my question: [Warm start of simplex algorithm after update of constraint matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412507/warm-start-of-simplex-algorithm-after-update-of-constraint-matrix). While reading Schrijver's book
"Theory of linear and integer programming" (reprint 1999) I encountered the following claim
(page 132, "the simplex method in tableau form"):

Given an $n \times m$ matrix $A$ and a nonsingular submatrix $C$ of
$\begin{pmatrix}-I_n\\A\end{pmatrix}$ consisting of $n$ rows of $\begin{pmatrix}-I_n\\A\end{pmatrix}$. Let $B$ the
$m \times m$ submatrix of $\begin{pmatrix}A&I_m\end{pmatrix}$ which consists
  of exactly thoses columns of $\begin{pmatrix}A&I_m\end{pmatrix}$ whose corresponding row of $\begin{pmatrix}-I_n\\A\end{pmatrix}$ is not in $C$. Then Schrijver writes "the nonsingularity of $C$ immediately gives the nonsingularity of $B$". (Note that $I_n$ denotes the $n \times n$ unit matrix.)

Clearly, this claim holds for the situation where $C$ consists of the $n$
top rows of $\begin{pmatrix}-I_n\\A\end{pmatrix}$, i.e.
$C=I_n$ and nonsingular. Then $B$ consist of the remaining last $m$ columns of $\begin{pmatrix}A&I_m\end{pmatrix}$, i.e. $B=I_m$ and, hence, also nonsingular. But in general this claim is not clear to me.

Could you please help me proving this claim, or give me some hint? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for simplicity (but without loss of generality) that you select last $n-k$ rows of $-I_n$ and first $k$ rows of $A$ for some $k$ between $0$ and $n$ to form your $C$. Partitioning $A$ in the form
$$
A=\pmatrix{A_{11}&A_{12}\\A_{21}&A_{22}},
$$
where $A_{11}$ is $k\times k$, we have that 
$$
C=\pmatrix{0_{(n-k)\times k}&-I_{n-k}\\A_{11}&A_{12}}.
$$
Since $C$ is nonsingular, so is $A_{11}$.
By construction,
$$
B=\pmatrix{A_{11}&0_{k\times(m-k)}\\A_{21}&I_{m-k}}.
$$
is nonsingular.

The general case can be treated similarly. If you select rows $\alpha\subset\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of $-I_n$ and rows $\beta\subset\{1,\ldots,m\}$ of $A$ such that $|\alpha|+|\beta|=n$, the nonsingularity of both $C$ and $B$ is determined by the nonsingularity of the square $|\beta|\times|\beta|$ matrix $A(\beta,\{1,\ldots,n\}\setminus\alpha)$.